# I have two exact same Java method and I want to create a generic one, how should I do it?

Tags: java

```
private void extracted(Principal principal, UnoBorrowerStaging unoBorrowerStaging, Integer status, String remarks,
            UnoBorrowerStagingRepo unoBorrowerStagingRepo, UnoBorrowerDetails unoBorrowerDetails) {
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String unoBorrowerDetailsAsString = null;
    try {
        unoBorrowerDetailsAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(unoBorrowerDetails);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    unoBorrowerStaging.setIs_processed(status);
    unoBorrowerStaging.setRemarks(remarks);
    unoBorrowerStaging.setPayload(unoBorrowerDetailsAsString);
    unoBorrowerStaging.setCreatedBy(principal.getName());

    unoBorrowerStagingRepo.save(unoBorrowerStaging);
}
```

```
private void extracted2(Principal principal, UnoDocumentsStaging unoDocumentsStaging, Integer status,
            String remarks, UnoDocumentsStagingRepo unoDocumentsStagingRepo, UnoDocumentsEntity unoDocumentsEntity) {
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(unoDocumentsEntity);       
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {      
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   
    unoDocumentsStaging.setIs_processed(status);
    unoDocumentsStaging.setRemarks(remarks);
    unoDocumentsStaging.setPayload(jsonString);
    unoDocumentsStaging.setCreatedBy(principal.getName());
    
    unoDocumentsStagingRepo.save(unoDocumentsStaging);
}
```

These two method bodies are the same, but the arguments are different like the entity class. I want to create one generic method where I pass the object and create instance of those passing parameters, in that way I don't have to create separate methods.

The above code is for parsing JSON into string then insert al the details into a database.

Comment: I wouldn't even recommend doing it this way by having dedicated methods with specific params. This feels much like hard coding your code according to the available fields. Nonetheless, this is a valid question.

Comment: Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use type `Object` instead of `UnoDocumentsEntity` and `UnoBorrowerDetails`.

Look at the signature of the method `ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString(Object value)`

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)